# Is taking a sentence in English language and reformulate in french, a plagiarism

Tags: thesis, plagiarism

I am writing my PHD thesis in french, sometimes I took some sentences, phrases from english references and try to rewriting them in french so that the meaning is close.

Is this a plagiarism?

Comment: Do you cite your original source? Are you taking just a sentence at a time or whole passages?

Comment: Have you checked the plagiarism section of the student code of conduct for your school/department? It may include a clause specifically about translated work.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, basically taking someone's language, thoughts, ideas or expressions without correct referencing is plagiarism...

Edit based on comments:

If you reference the material correctly, even though you translated and / or paraphrased it, is fine.

Comment: The OP did not say that they were not giving correct referencing. It would not be plagiarism, and also not demote the OP's own work to say something like 'blah blah blah (LeBlanc, 1793 - current author's translation)'

Comment: @JeremyC the OP did not make it clear that they were giving correct referencing either...

Comment: @SolarMike The response would be perfect if you added a condition. "If you do not reference ... . If you *do* reference, however, ..."